# Why does it go to the last onClick?

Tags: android, xml, uiimageview, onclick, expandablelistview

I have a xml with this list_child in a expandableListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clock"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="goMap"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_map"
        android:paddingLeft="105dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="goSchedule"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in both ImageView enters the last OnClick. Why?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain your problem ?

Comment: Did you mean that both ImageViews fire the same onClick method, which is goSchedule()? Please post your code...

Comment: `public void goSchedule(View view){

             Intent i = new Intent(this, TimeTableActivity.class );

             this.startActivity(i);
      }`

Comment: why not use onClicklistener for both pragmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not aligning your imageViews properly.
Do it this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="goMap"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clock"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="goSchedule"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. You are right. And if I want to put more space between both imageView?

Comment: Add marginLeft or marginRight to your imageViews.Try my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using paddingLeft for both ImageViews in a RelativeLayout. So the second ImageView is getting over the first one. Although you are seeing both views but the second view is on top of the first one. Use layout_marginLeft property instead of paddingLeft.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/clock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:onClick="goMap"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:onClick="goSchedule"
    android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```